# How create field weeks in between two dates

Tags: python, pandas

How to calculate using pandas weeks between two dates such `2019-12-15 and 2019-12-28`

Data:

```
cw = pd.DataFrame({ "lead_date" : ["2019-12-28" , "2019-12-23"] ,
                    "Received_date" : ["2019-12-15" , "2019-12-21"  ]  })
```

So I could do something like

`cw["weeks_between"]= ( cw["lead_date"] - cw["Received_date"]) / 7`

The problem is..

- For row 1:
  it will return 1.85, but is wrong value because one day starts in on beginning of week Vs End of week
- For row 2:
  It will return 0.28, but also wrong because one day starts end of week Vs beginning of week.

-

#### So how can I get the number of weeks in between this two dates?

Comment: What would your expected output be in this case? First row 2 weeks and second row 1 week?

Comment: exacly, it worked great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Method 1: Using `list comprehension`, `dt.period` & `getattr`

provided by [`Jon Clements`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59504914/how-create-field-weeks-in-between-two-dates#comment105182760_59504967) in comments

This method will work when years change between the compared dates:

```
cw['weeks_diff'] = (
    [getattr(el, 'n', 0) 
     for el in cw['lead_date'].dt.to_period('W') - cw['Received_date'].dt.to_period('W')]
)
```

---

#### Method 2: using weeknumbers with `dt.strftime('%W')`

We can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert your dates to datetime. Then we use the `dt.strftime` accessor to get the weeknumbers with `%W`.

Finally we substract both weeknumbers:

```
weeks = (cw[['lead_date', 'Received_date']]
         .apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.strftime('%W'))
         .replace('NaT', 0)
         .astype(int)
        )

cw['weeks_diff'] = weeks['lead_date'] - weeks['Received_date']

    lead_date Received_date  weeks_diff
0  2019-12-28    2019-12-15           2
1  2019-12-23    2019-12-21           1
```

Comment: I got error, my bad. It because I have some rows with NaT values, do you know something to avoid that. error: ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NaT'
 ```

Comment: Depends, what do you want to do with the missing dates? Do you want to drop them from your data, do you want to fill them with a dummy data, for example date of today?

Comment: fill with 0 or NaN, None

Comment: See edit, this should work @Peter. In this case I use `replace` since our dates will be converted to string after using `dt.strftime`

Comment: @Erfan I'm a little cautious about this answer as `%W` is the week number within a year... so if you change the `Received_date` in row 1 to be "2020-01-01" - then you end up with a `weeks_diff` of 51 which doesn't seem right to me?

Comment: I agree, I had the same problem/discussion at work today. We had to calculate the difference in months of dates. But what is a month exactly? Is that `30,5` days? Or the amount of hours in a year divided by 12? There's no arbitrary way to calculate this. I think same is applicable here right? @JonClements

Comment: @Erfan well - it depends... I think in the OP's case here, it might be possible to anchor to some week boundary (so you might for month calculations anchor to the start of each month for instance) - in this case, I don't think it matters what the anchor is, but if you convert them to the same "period" and then take the difference between the dates and account for NaT's, then I think something like: `cw['weeks_diff'] = [getattr(el, 'n', 0) for el in cw['lead_date'].dt.to_period('W') - cw['Received_date'].dt.to_period('W')]` might just work. That should work across years and stuff at least...

Comment: That's a nice trick never was aware of that. Talking about the `getattr`, still don't understand exactly how it works. You mind if I post it in my answer? @JonClements

Comment: Feel free Erfan

Answer (score 2):

You need to use convert to datetime using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ "lead_date" : ["2019-12-28" , "2019-12-23"] ,
                "Received_date" : ["2019-12-15" , "2019-12-21"  ]  })

df['lead_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['lead_date'])
df['Received_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Received_date'])
```

Here is the difference in days between "lead_date" and "Received_date"

```
df['time_between'] =df['lead_date']-df['Received_date']

print(df.head())

 lead_date Received_date time_between
0 2019-12-28    2019-12-15      13 days
1 2019-12-23    2019-12-21       2 days
```

Update: edits below to get number of weeks.  Also added import pandas and numpy.

To get 'time_between' column in weeks:

```
df['time_between']= df['time_between']/np.timedelta64(1,'W')
```

will yield

```
 lead_date Received_date  time_between
0 2019-12-28    2019-12-15      1.857143
1 2019-12-23    2019-12-21      0.285714
```

Update 2:  If you want week number subtractions and not days between then use:

```
df['lead_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['lead_date']).dt.week 
df['Received_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Received_date']).dt.week
df['time_between'] =df['lead_date']-df['Received_date']
```

yields,

```
    lead_date  Received_date  time_between
0         52             50             2
1         52             51             1
```

.dt.week returns week number in the year.

Comment: Can we get the difference by number of weeks? like in this case.. will be 1 week for row 1 and also 1 week for row 2

Comment: Yes, above code change will be df['time_between']= df['time_between']/np.timedelta64(1,'W') .  I'll edit the post to reflect this change.

Comment: @Peter I'm confused... Doesn't this give the same results that in your Q you've said are not what you want?

Comment: Jon Clements: Yes, you are right.  I just added week of the year subtraction vs days between dates.